# Unable to access SSH or ping instance after updating GCP OS

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, cloud, google

I have a cluster of instances in Google Cloud Platform that was accessible. I ran updates on a VM, then rebooted it. I have not been able to access the VM since. SSH fails, saying it cant be reached. I also cannot ping the instance. When I connect via the console port, it is flooded with martian source logs.

```
martian source x.x.x.x <affected machine> from x.x.x.x <some other ip>, on dev eth0
ll header: 42:01:0a:8e:00:05:42:01:0a:8e:00:01:08:00
Jul 11 20:07:40 <servername> kernel: __ratelimit: 3 callbacks suppressed
```

It is only affecting the machines that have been updated and rebooted. The ones that have been updated but NOT rebooted are fine (so far). I also checked the firewall-rules, and there is the default SSH rule.

I did find that if I clone an affected VM and give it a new OS disk, I can access it afterwards.

Any ideas? I am at a loss as to what to do with the ones that have been (and have not been) updated.

Answer (score 1):

I found the fix for me. A recent update has a known issue where it removes the default gateway from the iptables. To fix it, I have to go to the instance and select Edit. Scroll down, and under Custom Metadata put the following:

```
key: startup-script
value: route add default gw <gatewayIP> eth0
```

Save and restart the VM.

Comment: It took me a bit to figure this out - the IP of the Default Gateway is the second address in the primary IP range for the subnet. For example, if the primary IP range is 10.1.2.0/24, then the Default Gateway IP is 10.1.2.1 [VPC docs](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc)